# How to compute Mean Shift or K Means in n dimensions in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-science

I am trying to find clusters in my n dimensional data. I tried:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift

arr_3d = np.array([...])
arr_3d.shape # (2, 6, 2)
cluster = MeanShift().fit(arr_3d)
```

This gives an error

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <=2.
```

Reshaped data is confusing and I'd like to avoid it. I'm not attached to using sci kit learn, I just want n-dimensional mean shift or K means in a python library. How do I do this?

Comment: If your data has a shape (2, 6, 2), then how many features are there? Also, how many samples?

Comment: The 2, 6, 2 is just a trivial example. I haven't decided what features to use on my real dataset. I wanted to get started on this part first

Comment: The question still stands. Is that the shape of a single sample? Or said another way, you want kmeans on 2D data? Or 3D? I think with sklearn you would have to reshape. The only alternative I know would be to code it yourself

Comment: I was afraid of that. It will be one sample at a time, each with at least 5 dimensions. I'll steel myself for reshaping, thank you!

Comment: This is embarrassing... if I have 10 samples of 5 features... I need a 10x5 table, which is "2D," right?

Comment: No problem. You are right. According to the documentation, you should pass it in with a shape (n_samples, n_features). Which is a "2D" matrix 10x5 in your case.